# can't run the openwhisk-node-simple-http-endpoint example locally

Tags: serverless, serverless-framework, api-gateway, openwhisk

I am trying to run this simple openwhisk http endpoint [example](https://github.com/serverless/examples/tree/v3/openwhisk-node-simple-http-endpoint) on a local Openwhisk instance. When I try to deploy the example using the command `severless deploy` , I get the following error:

```
Compiling Functions...
Compiling Packages...
Compiling API Gateway definitions...
Compiling Rules...
Compiling Triggers & Feeds...
Compiling Service Bindings...
Deploying Functions...
Deploying API Gateway definitions...
Environment: linux, node 16.15.1, framework 3.21.0, plugin 6.2.2, SDK 4.3.2
Docs:        docs.serverless.com
Support:     forum.serverless.com
Bugs:        github.com/serverless/serverless/issues

Error:
Failed to deploy API Gateway route due to error: POST http://172.17.0.1:3233/api/v1/web/whisk.system/apimgmt/createApi Returned HTTP 502 (Bad Gateway) --> "API creation failure: Unable to configure the API Gateway (status code 400): {"status":400,"message":"Error: Resource path must begin with '/'."}"
```

I am starting the local Openwhisk instance using the command `java -jar openwhisk-standalone.jar --api-gw` as given [here](https://github.com/apache/openwhisk/blob/master/core/standalone/README.md) .

What could be the reason behind the API Gateway not being deployed?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.